# Unlock wp7/8 using bluetooth/nfc proximity

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I've been looking for documentation on whether or not it is possible to unlock windows phone 7 or 8 using Bluetooth or NFC, and thus far haven't been able to find anything. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: No. space filler here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't unlock a windows phone without using the screen.